# SDL2 Key Repeat not working

Tags: c++, event-handling, sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying to make a simple character that can move around a shoot bullets. My event handler currently looks like this:

```
    while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 ) {
        if( e.type == SDL_QUIT ) {
            quit = true;
        } else if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN && e.key.repeat == 0) {
           switch (e.key.keysym.sym) {
               case SDLK_UP:
                   p->setVelY(-1);
                   break;
               case SDLK_DOWN:
                   p->setVelY(1);
                   break;
               case SDLK_LEFT:
                   p->setVelX(-1);
                   break;
               case SDLK_RIGHT:
                   p->setVelX(1);
                   break;
               case SDLK_SPACE:
                   cout << "Firing" << endl;
                   p->Fire();
                   break;
           }
       } else if (e.type == SDL_KEYUP && e.key.repeat == 0) {
           ...
```

The problem is that if I hold the space bar, I only want my character to fire once. Right now though, it fires once, delays for like a quarter second, and then rapidly continues to fire. From my understanding, the repeat flag was the way to avoid this problem? It isn't working currently however. I saw somewhere to use scancodes instead, but I still had the same problem. I could make a map manually, but I wanted to just use the built in way to avoid key repeats. I'm currently using SDL 2.0.5 on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm just starting with SDL, so any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** Still not working, but I see now that the KEYUP is happening immediately in the next frame after every KEYDOWN, but then a new KEYDOWN is triggered (while I am still holding the key), and so forth. So it just keeps rapidly doing keydown and up events. This doesn't even let me do my own mapping for key press / release... any ideas?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Are you getting the same results in minimal possible program? Does `xev` reports this events as synthetic? Does delay/repeat rate changes if you modify it in your environment settings (i.e. keyboard can repeat by itself, then there is no way for X to know it is repeated).

Comment: Yes, I am getting the same results in the minimal possible program. No the events are not synthetic. The delay/repeat rates do change if I modify them. Are you compiling and linking against 2.0.5? I have another laptop on 2.0.4 and I do not get the same issue.

Comment: Sorry it appears I was wrong, problem indeed occurs with SDL 2.0.5 at least on ubuntu, but not with 2.0.4. It appears to be fixed in latest hg though.

Comment: Yes, I got the latest hg now, and it works. I preferred apt-get, but oh well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It mimics the type and hold action we see when typing. I'm not sure if there's another workaround but what I did was I checked for key downs and key ups to exclude key holds with a range of delay in between.